# Non-ASCII character in notebook

Tags: windows, python-3.6

I have a notebook that i want to convert to html using nbconvert. When i start the conversion, it throws this exception: "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 18919:..."
"0xd7" = ×

The module used for displaying is called iPython. I want it to display the header of the dataframe using ASCII characters so this error doesn't happen, anyone know how to do this? Thanks
I can use print instead but its ugly and doesnt really solve anything, but avoid the problem

[I want to change the weird × for an ascii character like x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHVLP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... In the end i just came up with a workaround.

This piece of code opens the notebook after its generated, as a binary file, looks for the byte "0xd7" and changes it for the common, friendlier version of an "X", "0x78".
Hope it helps to anyone that encounters the same problem, cheers.

```
####
with open(notebook, 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()

contents = contents.replace(b'\xd7',b'\x78')
with open(notebook, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(contents)
####
```